# Table for dummies in R

Tags: r, dummy-variable

Suppose my data seems the following. Columns `v1-v3` and `w1-w3` are the dummies of the variables named `V` and `W`, respectively.

```
v1 v2 v3 w1 w2 w3
 1  0  0  0  1  0
 0  1  0  0  0  1
 0  0  1  1  0  0 
 1  0  0  0  1  0
 0  1  0  0  0  1
 0  0  1  1  0  0
```

My intention is to produce a frequency table considering `v1, v2, v3` as rows & `w1, w2, w3` as columns. Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid I can only do it with loops. There might well be a more elegant way to do this in R but at least it works.

I don't know what you want to put in the cells when using v1-3 as rows and w1-3 as columns. You might put the times the values were the same or the times the values were 1. Or any other formula. In the example below, I tried two different ways (one is commented out)

```
dta = data.frame(v1=c(1,0,0,1,0,0),
                 v2=c(0,1,0,0,1,0),
                 v3=c(0,0,1,0,0,1),
                 w1=c(0,0,1,0,0,1),
                 w2=c(1,0,0,1,0,0),
                 w3=c(0,1,0,0,1,0))


t = matrix(NA,nrow=3,ncol=3)
colnames(t)=names(dta[4:6])
rownames(t)=names(dta[1:3])
for(r in rownames(t)){
  for(c in colnames(t)){
    t[r,c]=sum(dta[[r]]==dta[[c]]) ## Agreement
    #t[r,c]=sum(dta[[r]]==1 & dta[[c]]==1) ## Both are 1
  }
}
```

The script first creates the table and then loops through all cells to fill them in with the correct value, taking information from the original dataset.

For agreement, this matrix would result:

```
> print(t)
   w1 w2 w3
v1  2  6  2
v2  2  2  6
v3  6  2  2
```

This means that, for example, v1 and w2 agree in 6 cases, while the agreement of v1 with w1 is only 2.

Comment: Can I ask you one question more, please? Is that possible to calculate some statistics that help us to measure the level of agreement (like contingency cofficient or other)? Tnx!

Comment: Of course, yes. In the innermost part of the loops, where `t[r,c]` is defined, you have two vectors to work with. Vector `dta[[r]]` is the v-column and `dta[[c]]` is the w-column you take for this cell. You can use any function that takes two dummy vectors of equal length to compute statistics (e.g.: Agreement, Precision, Recall, Kappa, Krippendorff's Alpha, Sokal Distance,...). Just use these two vectors.

Answer (score 3):

We can `unlist` the first three column into a vector, similar to the last three columns and apply `table`

```
table(v = unlist(df1[1:3]), w = unlist(df1[4:6]))
```

---

If the OP meant to do the combination equality, then an option is `outer`

```
out <- outer(1:3, 4:6, FUN =  Vectorize(function(i, j) sum(df1[[i]] == df1[[j]])))
dimnames(out) <- list(names(df1)[1:3], names(df1)[4:6])

out
#   w1 w2 w3
#v1  2  6  2
#v2  2  2  6
#v3  6  2  2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(v1 = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), v2 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
0), v3 = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), w1 = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), w2 = c(1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0), w3 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: This produces only one table.

Comment: @Gada can you show your expected output in the post as it was not clear

Comment: @Gada do you need `lapply(split.default(df1, sub("\\d+$", "", names(df1))), function(x) table(unlist(x)))`

Comment: Ah, nice. There's the more elegant way I did not know ;) I was almost certain it was possible without loops. The outer() function is something I need to remember.